# iOS Core Data Abstract and Child Classes

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, abstract

I'm working on adding CoreData to an existing iOS project, and am having problems with data showing up in my child classes that inherit from an abstract class.

I have an abstract class (`Object`) that defines a shared set of fields for my desired child entity/concrete classes.  The abstract class contains `title`, `startDate`, for example.  It's setup in the data model to have a parent entity of `Object`.  `Object` is setup as an abstract class in the data model.

My child entity (`Expense`) has a property `amount` (among others).

I typically would begin creating my Expense as so:

```
Expense *expense = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([Expense class]) inManagedObjectContext:[Store sharedStore].managedObjectContext];
```

Then set my desired properties:

```
expense.amount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:amountString];
expense.title = title;
expense.startDate = [NSDate dateFromString:dateString withFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
(other properties on expense set here)
.
.
```

I'd then call save on my context:

```
[[Store sharedStore].managedObjectContext save:&error];
```

This returns `YES` for being stored to CoreData.

**HOWEVER**, when I try to LOG the expense's amount (or any of its other set properties), they come out as nil, 0, etc. depending on the property type.

I have other base entities/models in my project saving fine in this fashion, so it's nothing to do with my CoreData setup or Store class handling the object context.  Specific problem arose with the abstract class.

How do I setup my child entities of my abstract class in a way that it will correctly save the properties on that child class? I'm spinning my wheels and can't seem to find a good example of how to do so in Apple docs or anywhere online.  Anything is appreciated. :)

Comment: Did you check that `expense` is not `nil`? Is `expense.amount = nil` immediately after you assign a value or only after you save the context?

Comment: In the simplest case, this works fine.  I tried a test by setting up an abstract parent with a child, creating a child, assigning arbitrary values and saving.  Logging the object immediately after the save shows: "(entity: Expense; id: 0x7496dc0 <x-coredata://87AB064D-775A-4C19-8AE7-31A84A9332F4/Expense/p2> ; data: {
    amount = 5;
    startDate = "2012-10-20 13:35:42 +0000";
    title = "Test title";
})".  There's something else going on that's not part of the code you posted.

Comment: expense is not nil, and it appropriately saved the ```Object```'s values on the Expense object.  However it does not save the properties that are on the Expense entity itself (amount being one of them).  @PhillipMills do you have any idea where my problem could arise?  My logs look like yours except amount = 0. :(  Anything else you can think of I could share?

Comment: Here's the expense log......

<Expense: 0x9a59d10> (entity: Expense; id: 0x9a3e780 <x-coredata://007C3D01-2E8C-4C03-B587-E1C5FF15B33E/Expense/p48> ; data: {
    amount = 0;
    objectDescription = "paid to \"Objects of America\" from [Credit Card]";
    payee = "";
    startDate = "2012-10-12 05:00:00 +0000";
    title = nil;
})

......where ```payee``` and ```amount``` exist on an Expense, and ```objectDescription``` and ```startDate``` exist on the ```Object```.

Comment: What's your actual definition of `amount` in Core Data?  (I just used int32 and `expense.amount = @(5);` in the code to make it save some value there.)  Also, what other fields are in `Expense` in your case?

Comment: Regardless of the ```amount``` type, I have a field ```payee``` that is being sent across from my API, has a value when sent to the method that executes the insert above, but has a value of ```""``` when set on the ```Expense``` object itself.

......here's the definition of the Expense:

```amount``` (Decimal)
```payee``` (String)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much debugging, and directly contacting @PhillipMills, we were able to land on the problem, and I hope others don't have to spend time pulling their hair out. :)

Having `- (void)setAmount` and `- (void)setPayee` methods on the `Object` class were causing the desired setters to be overridden.  I didn't intentionally implement these, but they existed on my `Object` class before I introduced CoreData into my project.

Removing those getters and setters on the Object class made things work as expected.  Much thanks to Phillip for his help!